# Text is not displayed on Button Widget

Tags: android, button, text, shapes

I tried all day yesterday and I can not fix it. 
I've searched for answers but have not found anything similar to my problem. 
It is probably easy to solve but I do not get it.

I have the following simple code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ... ...   >

<LinearLayout
    ... ...  >


   <Button
    android:id="@+id/registrarUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:text="@string/registrar"
    android:textColor="@color/tinto" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y cannot  display the text on the button!!

Here my `strings.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Android GCM</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="btn_aceptar">Aceptar</string>
    <string name="reg_gcm">Reg GCM</string>
    <string name="btn_desreg_gcm">DesReg GCM</string>
    <string name="nombre_usuario">Usuario</string>
    <string name="registrar">Registrar</string>

</resources>
```

And here my `button_shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#80000000"
        android:endColor="#80f2f2f2"
        android:angle="-90"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="13dp" />
</shape>
```

Even removing the `android:background="@drawable/button_shape"` (I thought it might be the problem.) it does't work.

In the console I can see the correct text displayed on the button... but not when I'm running the proyect in my device ... :(

[image]
What am I doing wrong? I am fairly new to this and not I find the error.

Someone has the same thing happened? any suggestions, please? 
Thank you very much in advance!

EDITED:

Problem solved!!!!

I just realized that "LinerarLayout" had a fixed "height" set! That cut the button!!
So, I changed

`"android: layout_height =" 200DP "` by `"android: layout_height =" wrap_content "`
  and that was all!

[image]

I hope it helps someone else to not waste so much time on something as "silly".

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What color is this tinto? try to set the black then see and see are you resetting the text at run time ?

Comment: Please share your Java Code (Activity Code)

Comment: As I am seeing a text on the button, then might some issue in your Activity

Comment: Activity edited... Is anyone seeing something there?

Comment: "tinto" is this <color name="tinto">#a80329</color>...but en with black it's not working.

Comment: Are you using a 9Patch Image as the background of your button ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your Button's Text Color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
... ...   >

<LinearLayout
... ...  >


 <Button
android:id="@+id/registrarUser"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="15dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
android:text="@string/registrar"
android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try to set the Button's Text Color as Black or White (What ever best contrasts your Button's Background) 
I hope this helps.

Comment: I've already tried. Even with its own color colors.xml saved and has not worked either. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please share your Java code, i guess there is some problem with it.

Comment: ok.. ;) It's amazing how much time is lost sometimes as basic and simple things! regards!